# Arranging a list of vectors according to the sum of square of each element

Tags: r, list, sorting

```
x <- list(c(1,2), c(1,4), c(1,1))
```

I want to arange the vectors of the list according to their sum of square of the elements of each vector.

Sum of squares of three vectors:

```
1^2 + 2^2 = 5,

1^2 + 4^2 = 17,

1^2 + 1^2 = 2.
```

Since, `2 < 5 < 17`, the desired output will be:

```
   vectors   squaresum
    c(1,1)    2

    c(1,2)    5

    c(1,4)    17
```

I was thinking to build a function for square sum. Then using that function to sort the vectors. But could not do properly. Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go iterate over your list to calculate the sum of squares of each vector and use `order()` to get the indices of values in ascending order. You can then use those to sort your initial list `x`:

```
x[order(sapply(x, function(v) sum(v ** 2)))]
```

the result is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach which can be used if the list vectors are all ofthe same length:

```
x[order(rowSums(do.call(rbind, x)^2))]

[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 4
```

however it looks it does not provide any speed benefits on bigger lists compared to @clemens (I really thought it would):

```
x <- replicate(10000, sample(1:1000, 100, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(clemens = x[order(sapply(x, function(v) sum(v ** 2)))],
               missuse = x[order(rowSums(do.call(rbind, x) ^ 2))])
#output
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 clemens 32.03712 34.65821 59.16911 43.51531 57.19269 822.7295   100   a
 missuse 32.84621 35.33422 47.53151 42.69733 56.09183 107.2334   100   a
```